# capturing touch events without consuming them

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, touch-event

I've got a big headache and spent a few hours to solve my problem withou any reasonable results.

I use a custom adapter (extending `ArrayAdapter`) to show listview items. This adapter implements `OnTouchListener`. There's also a background selector which color is changing when an item is touched and `OnItemClickListener` in `ListViewActivity`.

What I need is capture touch events (all of them, not only `ACTION_DOWN`) in the adapter. When `onTouch` returns false, the consecutive events (`ACTION_CANCEL`, `ACTION_UP` etc.) aren't captured. On the other hand returning true stops dispatching all other events (e.g. click) so that the ListViewActivity's `onItemClick` is never triggered.

I tried hard to find any working solution in SO and other resources, but with no success.

One idea was not worry about click events and background. I may set the background programatically and trigger click event the same way when the `onTouch` action is `ACTION_UP`, but `view.performClick()` does nothing (view is the 1st argument of `onTouch` method).

**[EDIT]**

To make it clear, I want to handle touch events in the adapter beacuse I need the textview in the item to marquee when the user touches it. Thus, in `onTouch`, when the action equals `ACTION_DOWN`, I assign `true` to setSelected property of the textview and, consequently, `false` when `ACTION_CANCEL` or `ACTION_UP`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ListView`-s are a pain to use, it's better to avoid them and use `LinearLayout` + `ScrollView` if possible. Also checkout these 2 functions about intercepting touch events: [onInterceptTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) , [requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29) , [more info](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html)